# Some keys on laptop keyboard stick on prt sc when pressed. Why?

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, troubleshooting, laptop-repair

If I press `G` `H` `delete` and probably some other keys I haven't discovered yet, it's similar to pressing and holding the `prt sc` key to take a screenshot, although they do their core function also. E.g. If I press `G` one time, it will type `G` one time as well as simultaneously repeatedly press `prt sc`. It doesn't unstick until I restart the laptop, or after hundreds of screenshots. The actual `prt sc` key does nothing.
Also the key `F` is not working.

At first it was the keys `I` `O` `P` and a couple of other ones that weren't working. Now those keys are working normally.

I tried cleaning the connector but that hasn't resolved the issue. Using an external keyboard works normally.
This issue pressists even when not using Windows but rather Ubuntu through Live USB or even WinPE.

I'd like to know what is causing this issue and if I can fix it.

If there is absolutely nothing I can do to fix it and if the problem is the keyboard and it needs to be replaced, I'd like to make sure it's indeed the keyboard and replacing it would resolve the problem.
I'll have to order one and can't test prior to doing so. I don't want to do that and then realize it's not because of the keyboard but rather due to the female connector or something like that.

Thanks guys!

Comment: " don't want to do that and then realize .... due to the female connector"   <-- You know the external keyboard works properly. It is very likely the laptop keyboard. Have the machine serviced to confirm or eliminate other possibilities.

Comment: External keyboard does not use connector.